# PHP Yii framework just echoes AR class

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I just started writing my first Yii application, but my AR class doesn't seem to work correctly.

This is my AR class:

```
class Activiteit extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'activiteit';
    }
}
```

This is my index view:

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name;

$activiteiten = Activiteit::model()->findAll();
?>
```

Somehow, this is the "html" generated:

```
class Activiteit extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'activiteit';
    }
}
```

Index action:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
   // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
   // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
   $this->render('index');
}
```

So, why does Yii just echo my AR class?

PS: without the $activiteiten = Activiteit::model()->findAll(); line, it generates the correct html page...

Comment: what does your action look like, the action that renders this view?

Comment: I added it to the question, also, if I comment "$activiteiten = Activiteit::model()->findAll();", it shows the correct page.

Comment: where have you stored the class file? is that what the entire class file looks like? you are most likely missing a `<?php` start tag somewhere, i'm guessing it's in your class file

Comment: which one is your view file index.php? if it is as you describe  then why you fetching data in view file?

Comment: Oh, that was it, I forgot the <?php ?> tags in the "Activiteit" class... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have stored and correctly written the class.

In common cases model files are stored in *projectname/protected/models/* folder.

And the class should be something like(say *Activiteit.php*):

```
<?php // i think you missed this start tag
   class Activiteit extends CActiveRecord
   {
      // ... your code ...
   }
```

Use [gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii) to auto generate code and avoid such mistakes.